# explain someone to someone

Tags: word-usage

I found examples for the phrase "explain someone (A) to someone (B)"

I am wondering if you are familiar with this usage. Could objects of "explain" be a person? It may make sense but I feel that it is unusual.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/explain+to+him
You can see some example in the URL.

Please explain Claire to me because ...

Can you explain Andrew to me?

Comment: Well, here the name *Claire* is a stand-in for the whole of Claire's personality. Complicated, it needs explaining. Explain Shakespeare: How is Romeo & Juliet a comedy? They kinda die, right? "How do you solve a problem like *Maria*?"

Comment: The phrase “explain women to me” shows up on NGram, e.g., “
Gill Paul · 2019 · ‎Preview · ‎More editions
“I wish you would explain women to me,” he said, gazing at her directly. “A great beauty like you must surely have insights that would help me to find a sweetheart.” So its unfamiliarity to you may simply be that you haven’t read widely enough.

Comment: The question answers itself by your remark that 'it may make sense but I feel that it is unusual'. The wording is not standard, but will be readily understood in the right context (e.g. there is something enigmatic about Claire's personality), and may be quite effective, if used carefully and sparingly.

Answer (score 1):

Having a specific person be the direct object sounds odd to me too. I searched [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for `explain _pp to` (with the middle term matching personal pronouns) and got the following:

- Many results for *it* and *them*, referring to things and not people.
- Many results using reflexives. Reflexive pronouns are undoubtedly idiomatic here.
- Less than 20 results for us/me/him/her/you combined, including a [quote by Mark Twain](https://books.google.com/books?id=7MykVRHA_SEC&pg=PA30&dq=%22IT%20WILL%20EXPLAIN%20US%20TO%20EACH%20OTHER%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJ2p_8iPLvAhUYEVkFHRcqAqwQ6AEwBHoECAQQAw).

Through my own searching, I found an [example in the New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1992/12/21/whose-art-is-it), using quotes likely because the usage isn’t very natural:

> They talked about how much a part of his community John was, and about trying to “explain” John to the people at D.G.S.—they were sure that if they did those people would understand that the last thing you could say about John Ahearn was that his work was racist.

It does sound idiomatic to say that you can “explain [a group of people]” (eg [women](https://www.quora.com/Will-someone-explain-women-to-me)) or “explain [an author]” (eg [Shakespeare](https://www.amazon.co.uk/review/R2I14B326N33EL)).

Comment: One can't help wondering, though, why would it be less idiomatic to ask someone to 'explain Claire to me' than to 'explain women to me'.